# Center section on navbar and collapse section on the right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm been stuck for longer than I'd like to admit on this issue. What I am trying to do is get the section which is displayed on the left to be displayed in the center(in a responsive manner).

[image: navbar]

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="irecipe-navbar-heading">
      <a>My Recipes</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="irecipe-logo-navbar">iRecipe</a>
    </li>
    <li class="irecipe-navbar-heading">
      <a>Discover</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarToggler">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#"></a><span class="material-symbols-outlined"> search </span>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> account_circle </span>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#"></a><span (click)="logout()" class="material-icons"> login </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have managed to center the iRecipe section when I remove the navbar by using

> `.justify-content-center`

After I insert the navbar and the

> `justify-content-end`

class, the result is the above navbar. I don't want to create a fake section which would allow me to justify the content equally using space-between. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm using bootstrap 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you there. What I did was I moved the logo outside of the  and then once on mobile used position absolute to place it in the center. You can replicate what I have

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.navbar { justify-content: flex-end; }

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```